# How to fix Class Cast Exception While Casting List View to PullToRefreshListView in android

Tags: android

I am using ListActivity in my application.I want to implement PullToRefreshListView for ListView in my application. I have implemented below code . I am getting ClassCast Exception.Can anybody tell how to fix it

```
 ((PullToRefreshListView)getListView()).setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

            Log.v("Inside the refresh","Inside the List");

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Add Web Service here
                //Constants.isQueueRefreshing=true;
                //new NewDataTask().execute();
            }
        });
```

logcat Error:

```
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.JobQueueDetailDescription}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1713)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:980)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3906)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at com.test.JobQueueDetailDescription.onCreate(JobQueueDetailDescription.java:40)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1677)
03-13 12:11:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(5242):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat then

Comment: link to [custom class](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshListView.java) OP appears to be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use normal activity instead of listactivity.

And add the pulltorefreshlistview inside the layout xml.

Then only you can covert it

```
<com.example.lotm.util.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/LotListView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: is it possible in LIstActivity to implement PullToRefreshListView